# Don't want to display months with no data set in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am trying to create a ggplot to display the data set that I have from January to September; however "October- December" displays in my visualization. Don't want it to be displayed. This only happend when i added +scale_x_discrete code to get my months displaying in the correct order.

```
structure(list(ride_id = c("E19E6F1B8D4C42ED", "DC88F20C2C55F27F", 
"EC45C94683FE3F27", "4FA453A75AE377DB", "BE5E8EB4E7263A0B"), 
    rideable_type = c("electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", 
    "electric_bike", "electric_bike"), started_at = structure(c(1611407640, 
    1611762180, 1611257700, 1610015460, 1611357840), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), ended_at = structure(c(1611408240, 
    1611762420, 1611257820, 1610016120, 1611357840), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), start_station_name = c("California Ave & Cortez St", 
    "California Ave & Cortez St", "California Ave & Cortez St", 
    "California Ave & Cortez St", "California Ave & Cortez St"
    ), start_station_id = c("17660", "17660", "17660", "17660", 
    "17660"), end_station_name = c("", "", "", "", ""), end_station_id = c("", 
    "", "", "", ""), start_lat = c(41.90034067, 41.90033283, 
    41.90031267, 41.90039867, 41.90032633), start_lng = c(-87.696743, 
    -87.696707, -87.69664267, -87.69666217, -87.69669717), end_lat = c(41.89, 
    41.9, 41.9, 41.92, 41.9), end_lng = c(-87.72, -87.69, -87.7, 
    -87.69, -87.7), member_casual = c("member", "member", "member", 
    "member", "casual"), ride_length = structure(c(10, 4, 2, 
    11, 0), class = "difftime", units = "mins"), date = structure(c(18650, 
    18654, 18648, 18634, 18649), class = "Date"), month = c("January", 
    "January", "January", "January", "January"), days_of_week = c("Saturday", 
    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Friday")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
monthly_trips <- data_trip_cleaned%>%
  filter(month=="January"|month=="February"|month=="March"|month=="April"|month=="May"|month=="June"|month=="July"|month=="August"|month=="September")

monthly_trips%>%
  group_by(member_casual)%>%
  summarise(totals=n())

ggplot(monthly_trips)+geom_bar(aes(x= month, fill= member_casual),position = "dodge")+labs(title = "Monthly trips, Member vs Casual",caption = "Data Source by Motivate Internatiol INC.")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50,hjust = 1))+scale_x_discrete(limits = month.name)
```

Output:

needs to display January- September and exclude October - December as their is no data for those months:

January,February,March,April,May,June,July.Augaust,September

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about how to give a reproducible example.

Comment: Try using the “droplevels” function.

Comment: `+scale_x_discrete(limits = month.name)` tells ggplot you want the x axis to have breaks for each of the values of `month.name`, ie all 12 months. Does removing that fix it?

Comment: FYI, for your line `monthly_trips <- data_trip_cleaned %>% filter(month=="January"|month=="February"...` you could replace with`...filter(month %in% months.name[1:9])`

Comment: Good day , @Dave2e, the droplevels function didn't work or gave the output I required .

Comment: Good day , @Dave2e, the droplevels function didn't work or gave the output I required .@ Jon Spring when I remove ```+scale_x_discrete(limits=month.name)```, my x axis resets to alphabetical order, I did try ```filter(month %in% months.name[1:9])``` and still het the same results in my ggplot